# When should I use InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, stream

From the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html) site, we know `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` can convert streams between bytes and characters.

`InputStreamReader` converts bytes read from input to characters, while `OutputStreamWriter` converts characters to bytes to output.

But when should I use this two classes?

We have `Inputstream/OutputStream` input/output byte by byte, and `Reader/Writer` input/output character by character.

So when using `InputStreamReader` to input characters from byte stream, why not just use `Reader` class (or its sub classes) to read character directly? Why not use `OutputStream` instead of `OutputStreamWriter` to write bytes directly?

---

***EDIT***:
When do I need to convert streams between bytes and characters using InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter?

---

***EDIT:***
Under which circumstances should I care about encoding scheme?

Comment: You only want to read text when you have text.  When you have binary e.g. an image, you read it as binary, you can't read it as text (or at least you shouldn't)

Comment: @PeterLawrey What you mean is correct. But it is not related to my question. For example, when you have binary e.g. an image, I can use InputStream/OutputStream to handle it. I am not saying I can read binary by character stream.

Comment: Using Stream for binary and Reader/Writer for text.  That answers your questions, but you seem to already know that so I am not sure what you are asking.  Perhaps you are assuming there is more to it than there is.  BTW InputStreamReader is a sub-class of Reader, but I guess you knew that too.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I understand now when handling String/char text message, I need to specify the encoding scheme like UTF-8. But when I use InputStream/OutputStream, why do I need not to specify the coding scheme?

Comment: Encodings describe how to convert between binary and text.  You don't have the same generic encodings between binary and binary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To understand the purpose of this, you need to get the following firmly into your mind.   In Java `char` and `String` are for "text" expressed as Unicode, and `byte` or `byte[]` are for binary data.  Bytes are NOT text.  Bytes can represent *encoded* text ... but they have to be *decoded* before you can use the `char` and `String` types on them.

> So when using `InputStreamReader` to input characters from byte stream, why not just use `Reader` class (or its sub classes) to read character directly?

(`InputStreamReader` is a subclass of `Reader`, so it not a case of "either ... or ...".)

The purpose of the `InputStreamReader` is to adapt an `InputStream` to a `Reader`.  This adapter takes care of decoding the text from bytes to chars which contain Unicode codepoints<sup>1</sup>.

So you would use it when you have an existing InputStream (e.g. from a socket) ... or when you need more control over the selection of the encoding scheme.  (Re the latter - you can open a file directly using `FileReader`, but that implicitly uses the default platforming encoding for the file.  By using FileInputStream -> InputStreamReader you can specify the encoding scheme explicitly.)

> Why not use OutputStream instead of OutputStreamWriter to write bytes directly?

Its encodings again.  If you want write text to an OUtputStream, you have to encode it according to some encoding scheme; e.g.

```
    os.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

By using a Writer, you move the encoding into the output pipeline where it is less obtrusive, and can typically be done more efficiently.

---

<sup>1 -  or more strictly, a 16-bit representation of Unicode codepoints.</sup>

Comment: So at Java language level, char and String (list of chars) are viewed as Unicode. But at device/file/storage level, everything (char and String included) is encoded by default encoding scheme. Is that right?

Comment: In java if there is a statement: String str = "abcdef"; As you said, str is expressed as Unicode in heap memory area. I want to store this str to file. If I use FileOutputStream, then what encoding scheme do I use? If I use FileWriter, what encoding shceme do I use?

Comment: 1) Yes, that is right.  2) If you use `FileOutputStream`, you will use the platform's default charset for encoding ... whatever that might be.

Comment: str is a kind of text (special text as ASCII chars). So I should use Reader/Writer, which is better, is that right? If I use FileOutputStream to write the str to file, I think there is encoding scheme involved since FileOutputStream write byte by byte. So my second comment has problem.

Comment: Actually, my last comment is incorrect (I was in a hurry!).  In fact ... 2) `FileOutputStream` has no methods that will directly write a `String`.  FileOUtputStream only has methods for writing bytes.  If you want to write a String, you have to use ... something else ... to encode the characters to bytes, and the encoding scheme used depends on how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

`Reader/Writer` give API to **read/write** the **String literals** into the stream. Where as `Inputstream/OutputStream` doesn't provide **read/write** of **String literals**, instead they read/write **byte by byte**.

So If your program needs to read/write **String**, then I advice using `Reader/Writer` for *simplicity*.

Also, `Reader/Writer` use `InputStream/OutputStream` internally, so Streams read/write *little faster* if used directly

Comment: So could you explain under which circumstances should I care about encoding scheme?